# Allow system accounts to login to other server without passwords

Tags: centos, ssh, redhat, public-key, private-key

i'd like to allow user 'devel' to login to any other server using public keys as user 'devel'. This user is not a human, but a scripting-only account. How can I accomplish this? Is Puppet the right way? How does each **source** server receive the necessary key material? I am *very* aware of the how private and public keys are used for SSH authentication and the degree of confidentiality that goes with private keys.

Assume there are 100 servers, and private & public keys need to be changed every 90 days.

Comment: Do you have Puppet (or any other configuration management) currently setup and in use?

Comment: @andol yes I do.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a possible use case for Hashicorp's [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/).

The [SSH Backend](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/ssh/) allows two modes of operation:

- one time passwords, which require installation of a helper component on each server which verifies users with Vault - beforehand clients query Vault though an API and for every access a new password is issued
- dynamic key - basically a proxy (in the sense of doing work for you) server generating key-pairs, issuing private key for clients and installing public ones on servers - with this method you need to distribute the Vault's "permanent" SSH key to servers, but then can set the expiration for keys issued to clients - when a key-pair expires, Vault removes th the corresponding public key from servers

Either method can be automated  for scripts. They would still need to authenticate with Vault, but you have a single point of control.